# Environment variable to tell chrome to work as root without no-sandbox flag?

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

Pretty much default debian images are now having root as default: Every command you run as root.

That leads to some nodejs package that depends on chrome/puppeteer to fail because chrome/puppeteer won't run without no-sandbox flag in such environment.

It's a pain in the ass because it's unpractical to trace down all the dependencies between nodejs package to add no-sandbox to the right spot.

Is there an environment variable like CHROME_NO_SANDBOX=true so that we can tell chrome to run despite of root mode?

Comment: Thers is an option ```'--no-sandbox'``` which you can pass in launch. Something like this - 
```await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            headless: true,
            slowMo: 800,
            args: ['--window-size=1920,1080', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        }
      );```
But I'm not sure whether this answer yours question

Comment: Only if it uses the QT-webengine: export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1

Comment: It seems that at Wikimdia they add such args parameterization directly in their grunt task https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5505#issuecomment-731933795